# Writing into csv file after BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup to extract some text, and then I want to save the entries into a csv file. My code as follows:

```
for trTag in trTags:
    tdTags = trTag.find("td", class_="result-value")
    tdTags_string = tdTags.get_text(strip=True)
    saveFile = open("some.csv", "a")
    saveFile.write(str(tdTags_string) + ",")
    saveFile.close()

saveFile = open("some.csv", "a")
saveFile.write("\n")
saveFile.close()
```

It did what I want for the most part EXCEPT whenever if there is a comma (",") within the entry, it sees it as a separator and split the single entry into two different cells (which is not what I want). So I searched around the net and found people suggested of using the csv module and I changed my codes into:

```
for trTag in trTags:
    tdTags = trTag.find("td", class_="result-value")
    tdTags_string = tdTags.get_text(strip=True)
    print tdTags_string

    with open("some.csv", "a") as f:
        writeFile = csv.writer(f)
        writeFile.writerow(tdTags_string)

saveFile = open("some.csv", "a")
saveFile.write("\n")
saveFile.close()
```

This made it even worse, now each letter/number of a word or number occupies a single cell in the csv file. For example, if the entry is "Cat". The "C" is in one cell, "a" is the next cell, and "t" is the third cell, etc.

Edited version:

```
import urllib2
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

SomeSiteURL = "https://SomeSite.org/xyz"
OpenSomeSiteURL = urllib2.urlopen(SomeSiteURL)
Soup_SomeSite = BeautifulSoup(OpenSomeSiteURL, "lxml")
OpenSomeSiteURL.close()

# finding name
NameParentTag = Soup_SomeSite.find("tr", class_="result-item highlight-person")
Name = NameParentTag.find("td", class_="result-value-bold").get_text(strip=True)
saveFile = open("SomeSite.csv", "a")
saveFile.write(str(Name) + ",")
saveFile.close()

# finding other info
# <tbody> -> many <tr> -> in each <tr>, extract second <td>
tbodyTags = Soup_SomeSite.find("tbody")
trTags = tbodyTags.find_all("tr", class_="result-item ")

for trTag in trTags:
    tdTags = trTag.find("td", class_="result-value")
    tdTags_string = tdTags.get_text(strip=True)

    with open("SomeSite.csv", "a") as f:
        writeFile = csv.writer(f)
        writeFile.writerow([tdTags_string])
```

2nd edition:

```
placeHolder = []

for trTag in trTags:
    tdTags = trTag.find("td", class_="result-value")
    tdTags_string = tdTags.get_text(strip=True)
    placeHolder.append(tdTags_string)

with open("SomeSite.csv", "a") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)
```

Updated output:

```
u'stuff1'
u'stuff2'
u'stuff3'
```

Output example:

```
u'record1'  u'31 Mar 1901'  u'California'

u'record1'  u'31 Mar 1901'  u'California'

record1     31-Mar-01       California
```

Another edited codes (still having one issue - skipping one line below):

```
import urllib2
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

SomeSiteURL = "https://SomeSite.org/xyz"
OpenSomeSiteURL = urllib2.urlopen(SomeSiteURL)
Soup_SomeSite = BeautifulSoup(OpenSomeSiteURL, "lxml")
OpenSomeSiteURL.close()

# finding name
NameParentTag = Soup_SomeSite.find("tr", class_="result-item highlight-person")
Name = NameParentTag.find("td", class_="result-value-bold").get_text(strip=True)
saveFile = open("SomeSite.csv", "a")
saveFile.write(str(Name) + ",")
saveFile.close()

# finding other info
# <tbody> -> many <tr> -> in each <tr>, extract second <td>
tbodyTags = Soup_SomeSite.find("tbody")
trTags = tbodyTags.find_all("tr", class_="result-item ")

placeHolder = []

for trTag in trTags:
    tdTags = trTag.find("td", class_="result-value")
    tdTags_string = tdTags.get_text(strip=True)
    #print repr(tdTags_string)
    placeHolder.append(tdTags_string.rstrip('\n'))

with open("SomeSite.csv", "a") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("some.csv", "a") as f:
        writeFile = csv.writer(f)
        writeFile.writerow([tdTags_string]) # put in a list
```

`writeFile.writerow` will iterate over what you pass in so a string `"foo"` becomes `f,o,o` three separate values,  wrapping it in a `list` will prevent this as writer will iterate over the list not the string

You should open your file once as opposed to every time through your loop:

```
with open("SomeSite.csv", "a") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    for trTag in trTags:
        tdTags = trTag.find("td", class_="result-value")
        tdTags_string = tdTags.get_text(strip=True) # 
        writeFile.writerow([tdTags_string])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (in terms of the comma and separate-cell issues), but somehow instead of putting different entries in a single row, it enters the subsequent entry at two rows below.

Comment: just make sure you are not writing newline chars, this will put entries on different lines

Comment: How do I make sure? I have posted my edited full codes here, I don't see where I might be asking for newline, and I thought the writerow function is supposed to be writing into a single line.

Comment: are you wanting to add all `tdTags_string` through the loop? print `repr(tdTags_string)` in the loop, it will show exactly what chars you are writing

Comment: you are also writing to a new row each time through the loop, not sure if you understand that or not.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have followed your tips. I have taken it out of the loop and created an empty list placeholder. Now everything for a single record is entered into a single row in appropriate cells. Just one last issue though, Every time I run the project, the new entry is entered two rows down, instead of immediate below the previous record's row.

Comment: You are Def writing an empty line or new line that you cannot see. Use repr to verify your output

Comment: With the repr(tdTags_string) inside the loop. The output looks as the most recent update. It added the u'(stuff)' part except the (stuff).

Comment: add a small but  of how the output looks in your file

Comment: Let me know if that's what you are referring to. I have added what the csv looks like. In such, I have run the program three times, the first two I have used repr(tdTags_string) in the loop, while the third time, only with (tdTags_string). As you can see, each time it's run, the "new" record is entered by skipping one line.

Comment: `print repr(placeHolder)`

Comment: I get ["u'record1'", "u'31 Mar 1901'", "u'California'"]

Comment: using your code and the placeholder it works fine but  if I add a `\n` it matches your output so there is a `\n`. Try appending  `tdTags_string.rstrip("\n")`

Comment: I have tried (see the latest updated codes above, but the csv still looks the same with skipping one row). I have posted the entire code thinking it will be easier for us to figure out. This is strange I am not sure where the "\n" would have come from.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest problem of skipping line, I have found an answer. Instead of

```
with open("SomeSite.csv", "a") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)
```

Use this:

```
with open("SomeSite.csv", "ab") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. The "a" mode is the appending mode, where as "ab" is an appending mode while opening the file as binary file which solves the problem of skipping one extra line.